# "export 'BrowserMultiFormatReader' was not found in '@zxing/browser'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, babeljs, webpacker, zxing-js

I have a rails project with webpacker, I was using `"@zxing/library": "^0.17.1"` for scanning barcode but as they have released a new library `"@zxing/browser"` so I am trying to upgrade to it. So I have added this to `package.json`:

```json
        "@zxing/browser": "^0.0.5",
        "@zxing/library": "^0.18.3",
```

and trying to use it like this in a js file:

```js
import { BrowserMultiFormatReader } from "@zxing/browser";
var a = new BrowserMultiFormatReader();
```

But when webpacker compiles it there is an error in terminal console:

```
ERROR in ./app/assets_js/xyz.js 2:12-36
"export 'BrowserMultiFormatReader' was not found in '@zxing/browser'
```

and on browser console it shows this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _zxing_browser__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.BrowserMultiFormatReader is not a constructor
```

The library was working previously on `0.17.1` version where it has the similar files not sure what I have done wrong here.

I have tried default import but that didn't work. I tried adding `ts-loader` or the babel-typescript library but that too didn't work. And actually as it worked previously I think it is not required to add any new library to transpile the library code.

**Library:**

In vscode if I ctrl + click the import (`@zxing/browser`) then I get this code in the `index.d.ts`

```
export { BarcodeFormat } from '@zxing/library';
export * from './common/HTMLCanvasElementLuminanceSource';
export * from './common/HTMLVisualMediaElement';
export * from './common/IScannerControls';
export * from './readers/BrowserAztecCodeReader';
export * from './readers/BrowserMultiFormatOneDReader';
export * from './readers/BrowserCodeReader';
export * from './readers/BrowserDatamatrixCodeReader';
export * from './readers/BrowserMultiFormatReader';
export * from './readers/BrowserPDF417Reader';
export * from './readers/BrowserQRCodeReader';
export * from './readers/IBrowserCodeReaderOptions';
export * from './writers/BrowserCodeSvgWriter';
export * from './writers/BrowserQRCodeSvgWriter';
```

and this is the code in `@zxing/browser/esm/readers/BrowserMultiFormatReader.d.ts` file:

```
import { BarcodeFormat, BinaryBitmap, DecodeHintType, MultiFormatReader, Result } from '@zxing/library';
import { BrowserCodeReader } from './BrowserCodeReader';
import { IBrowserCodeReaderOptions } from './IBrowserCodeReaderOptions';
export declare class BrowserMultiFormatReader extends BrowserCodeReader {
    set possibleFormats(formats: BarcodeFormat[]);
    protected readonly reader: MultiFormatReader;
    constructor(hints?: Map<DecodeHintType, any>, options?: IBrowserCodeReaderOptions);
    /**
     * Overwrite decodeBitmap to call decodeWithState, which will pay
     * attention to the hints set in the constructor function
     */
    decodeBitmap(binaryBitmap: BinaryBitmap): Result;
    /**
     * Allows to change hints in runtime.
     */
    setHints(hints: Map<DecodeHintType, any>): void;
}
```

If this helps somehow to point my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import from '@zxing/library/esm' instead of '@zxing/library/'
You can also try '@zxing/library/es2015'

I had the same problem, working fine with 0.17.1 but breaking when update to 0.18+, and those changes both fixed my problem. I decided to keep the es2015 one since it seems more modern to me. I think they introduced this breaking change in 0.18+ without referencing it in the docs.

I don't use @zxing/browser, but I guess you could try the same with that library as well.